# Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (JavaScript ES6)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

For example, if I have two objects:

```
var foo = {
  x: "bar",
  y: "baz"
}
```

and

```
var oof = {}
```

and I wanted to transfer the x and y values from `foo` to `oof`. Is there a way to do that using the ES6 destructuring syntax?

Perhaps something like:

```
oof{x,y} = foo
```

Comment: If you want to copy all properties `Object.assign(oof, foo)`

Comment: Lots of destructing examples [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), but I do not see the one you're asking about.

Comment: Hmm I couldn't find one either..

Comment: See my answer below for a two line solution without `Object.assign`

Answer (score 173, accepted):

While ugly and a bit repetitive, you can do

```
({x: oof.x, y: oof.y} = foo);
```

which will read the two values of the `foo` object, and write them to their respective locations on the `oof` object.

Personally I'd still rather read

```
oof.x = foo.x;
oof.y = foo.y;
```

or

```
['x', 'y'].forEach(prop => oof[prop] = foo[prop]);
```

though.

Comment: The alternative ['x', 'y'].forEach(prop => oof[prop] = foo[prop]); as I see, is the only one D.R.Y (do not repeat yourself), till now. "DRY" would be indeed useful in the case of several keys to be mapped. You would only need to update one place. Maybe I am wrong. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Third example is DRY, but you have to use strings as the keys, which javascript normally does implicitly. Not convinced that's less of a nuisance than:
 const {x, y} = foo; const oof = {x, y};

Comment: Can someone show me in jsfiddle where the first suggestion works?  It's not working here on chrome: https://jsfiddle.net/7mh399ow/

Comment: @techguy2000 You forgot the semicolon after `var oof = {};`.

Comment: In the first code, shouldnt be `({x: oof.x, y: oof.y} = foo)` ? I think you've put an extra _f_ in _oof_.

Comment: Most JS formatters will change `(` in the beginning of the line to `;(` which I think is a pretty clean solution to those kind of problems and you still can just omit the semicolons after each line.

Comment: can do `Object.keys(foo).forEach(prop => oof[prop] = foo[prop]);`

Comment: I personally like the syntax of the first example when changing from one case style to another, like this: `({ order_number: this.orderNumber, order_amount: this.orderAmount } = this.config);`

Comment: Just remember that code is written for people, not for computers. So, whatever option is easier to read is the best option, imho.

Comment: the first option is useful if the right side is a function and we don't want to create a temporary variable.
`({ x: this.x, y: this.y } = getXYZ());`

Answer (score 61):

**IMO, this is the easiest way to accomplish what you're looking for:**

```
let { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = someObject;
let data = { prop1, prop2, prop3 };

  // data === { prop1: someObject.prop1, ... }
```

Basically, destructure into variables and then use the initializer shorthand to make a new object. There isn't any need for `Object.assign`.

I think this is the most readable way, anyway. You can hereby select the exact props out of `someObject` that you want. If you have an existing object you just want to merge the props into, do something like this:

```
let { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = someObject;
let data = Object.assign(otherObject, { prop1, prop2, prop3 });
    // Makes a new copy, or...
Object.assign(otherObject, { prop1, prop2, prop3 });
    // Merges into otherObject
```

Another, arguably cleaner, way to write it is:

```
let { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = someObject;
let newObject = { prop1, prop2, prop3 };

// Merges your selected props into otherObject
Object.assign(otherObject, newObject);
```

I use this for [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) requests a lot where I only need a few pieces of discrete data. But, I agree there should be a one liner for doing this.

**P.S.:**

I recently learned you can use ultra destructuring in the first step to pull nested values out of complex objects! For instance...

```
let { prop1,
      prop2: { somethingDeeper },
      prop3: {
         nested1: {
            nested2
         }
      } = someObject;
let data = { prop1, somethingDeeper, nested2 };
```

Plus, you could use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) instead of Object.assign when making a new object:

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = someObject;
let finalObject = {...otherObject, prop1, prop2, prop3 };
```

Or...

```
const { prop1, prop2, prop3 } = someObject;
const intermediateObject = { prop1, prop2, prop3 };
const finalObject = {...otherObject, ...intermediateObject };
```

Comment: I like this approach, pragmatic.

Comment: This is what I do but it's not very dry. I think what a lot of people really need is just an extract keys function.

Comment: @jgmjgm yeah, it would be nice to have one built in but I guess thats not too hard to write either.

Answer (score 42):

No, destructuring does not support member expressions in shorthands, but only plain propertynames at the current time. There [have been talks](https://mail.mozilla.org/pipermail/es-discuss/2015-March/042195.html) about such on [ES Discuss](https://esdiscuss.org/about), but no proposals will make it into ES6.

You might be able to use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) however. If you don't need all own properties, you still can do:

```
var foo = …,
    oof = {};
{
    let {x, y} = foo;
    Object.assign(oof, {x, y})
}
```

Comment: @loganfsmyth, your example isn't working for me at least in my tests with node 4.2.2. with `--harmony_destructuring` enabled. I see "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ."

Comment: @loganfsmyth you should submit a proper answer as this is a very useful comment imo.

Comment: @Sulliwane: [He's done so (now)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624564/157247). Bergi, would probably be best to update the answer to call out that you *can* use member expressions as shown by Logan. (Is it really true that the spec changed that much between April and June 2015?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, I don't think it changed, I guess I was talking about `{oof.x, oof.y} = foo`. Or maybe I really had missed it.

Answer (score 14):

Other than `Object.assign`, there is the [object spread syntax](https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread#spread-properties) which is a Stage 2 proposal for ECMAScript.

```js
    var foo = {
      x: "bar",
      y: "baz"
    }

    var oof = { z: "z" }

    oof =  {...oof, ...foo }

    console.log(oof)

    /* result
    {
      "x": "bar",
      "y": "baz",
      "z": "z"
    }
    */
```

But to use this feature, you need to use `stage-2` or `transform-object-rest-spread` plugin for [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)). Here is a [demo on Babel with `stage-2`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-2&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&code=var%20foo%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20x%3A%20%22bar%22%2C%0A%20%20y%3A%20%22baz%22%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20oof%20%3D%20%7B%20z%3A%20%22z%22%20%7D%0A%0Aoof%20%3D%20%20%7B...oof%2C%20...foo%20%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(oof)).

Comment: This doesn't actually set the properties on the existing object, but rather creates a new object containing all the properties of both.

Answer (score 10):

## BabelJS plugin

If you are using **[BabelJS](https://babeljs.io/)** you can now activate my plugin `babel-plugin-transform-object-from-destructuring` ([see npm package for installation and usage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-object-from-destructuring)).

I had the same issue described in this thread and for me it was very exhausting when you create an object from a destructuring expression, especially when you have to rename, add or remove a property. With this plugin maintaining such scenarios gets much more easier for you.

#### Object example

```
let myObject = {
  test1: "stringTest1",
  test2: "stringTest2",
  test3: "stringTest3"
};
let { test1, test3 } = myObject,
  myTest = { test1, test3 };
```

can be written as:

```
let myTest = { test1, test3 } = myObject;
```

#### Array example

```
let myArray = ["stringTest1", "stringTest2", "stringTest3"];
let [ test1, , test3 ] = myArray,
  myTest = [ test1, test3 ];
```

can be written as:

```
let myTest = [ test1, , test3 ] = myArray;
```

Comment: This is precisely what I wanted. Thank you!

Comment: `let myTest = { test1, test3 } = myObject;` doesn't work

Answer (score 4):

You can just use restructuring for that like this:

```
const foo = {x:"a", y:"b"};
const {...oof} = foo; // {x:"a", y:"b"}
```

Or merge both objects if `oof` has values:

```
const foo = {x:"a", y:"b"};
let oof = {z:"c"}
oof = Object.assign({}, oof, foo)
```

Comment: I think this first case is exactly what I was looking for. I tried it out in the chrome console and it seems to work. Cheers! @campsafari

Comment: @majorBummer Your call in the end, but I'd consider approach to not actually answer your question, because these both create _new_ objects, rather than adding properties to _existing_ objects like your title asks.

Comment: That's a good point @loganfsmyth. I think I was just excited by the method campSafari brought up because I hadn't realized that that was possible.

Comment: If you dont mind creating a new object you could just do `oof = {...oof, ...foo}`

Comment: @JoshuaCoady `...=` operator when?

Answer (score 4):

It's totally possible. Just not in one statement.

```
var foo = {
    x: "bar",
    y: "baz"
};
var oof = {};
({x: oof.x, y: oof.y} = foo); // {x: "bar", y: "baz"}
```

(Do note the parenthesis around the statement.)
But keep in mind legibility is more important than code-golfing :).

Source: http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_destructuring.html#sec_assignment-targets

Answer (score 2):

You can return the destructured object in an arrow function, and use Object.assign() to assign it to a variable.

```
const foo = {
  x: "bar",
  y: "baz"
}

const oof = Object.assign({}, () => ({ x, y } = foo));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can destruct an object assigning directly to another object attribute.

Working example:

```js
let user = {};
[user.name, user.username] = "Stack Overflow".split(' ');
document.write(`
1st attr: ${user.name} <br /> 
2nd attr: ${user.username}`);
```

You can work with destructing using variables with the same name of object attribute you want to catch, this way you don't need to do:

```
let user = { name: 'Mike' }
let { name: name } = user;
```

Use this way:

```
let user = { name: 'Mike' }
let { name } = user;
```

The same way you can set new values to object structures if they have the same attribute name.

Look this working example:

```js
// The object to be destructed
let options = {
  title: "Menu",
  width: 100,
  height: 200
};

// Destructing
let {width: w, height: h, title} = options;

// Feedback
document.write(title + "<br />");  // Menu
document.write(w + "<br />");      // 100
document.write(h);                 // 200
```

Comment: `You can destruct an object assigning directly to another object attribute.`
In your first example you are destructuring an array, not an object.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
    var a = {a1:1, a2: 2, a3: 3};
    var b = {b1:1, b2: 2, b3: 3};
    
    const newVar = (() => ({a1, a2, b1, b2})).bind({...a, ...b});
    const val = newVar();
    console.log({...val});
    // print: Object { a1: 1, a2: 2, b1: 1, b2: 2 }
```

or

```js
    console.log({...(() => ({a1, a2, b1, b2})).bind({...a, ...b})()});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in Chrome 53.0.2785.89:

```js
    let foo = {
      x: "bar",
      y: "baz"
    };

    let oof = {x, y} = foo;

    console.log(`oof: ${JSON.stringify(oof)}`);

    //prints oof: { "x": "bar", "y": "baz"}
```

Comment: Sadly it seems like `oof` just receives a reference of `foo` and bypasses the whole destructuring (at least in Chrome). `oof === foo` and `let oof = { x } = foo` yet returns `{ x, y }`

Comment: @Theo.T good catch. that's a bummer, i'll have to find another way

Comment: This ones worth keeping just for demonstrating how JS can be confusing.

Comment: This works in every browser I test, but doesn't seem to work with Babel/Webpack.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this method:

```
exports.pick = function pick(src, props, dest={}) {
    return Object.keys(props).reduce((d,p) => {
        if(typeof props[p] === 'string') {
            d[props[p]] = src[p];
        } else if(props[p]) {
            d[p] = src[p];
        }
        return d;
    },dest);
};
```

Which you can use like this:

```
let cbEvents = util.pick(this.props.events, {onFocus:1,onBlur:1,onCheck:'onChange'});
let wrapEvents = util.pick(this.props.events, {onMouseEnter:1,onMouseLeave:1});
```

i.e., you can pick which properties you want out and put them into a new object. Unlike [`_.pick`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#pick) you can also rename them at the same time.

If you want to copy the props onto an existing object, just set the `dest` arg.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of cheating, but you can do something like this...

```
const originalObject = {
  hello: 'nurse',
  meaningOfLife: 42,
  your: 'mom',
};

const partialObject = (({ hello, your }) => {
  return { hello, your };
})(originalObject);

console.log(partialObject); // ​​​​​{ hello: 'nurse', your: 'mom' }​​​​​
```

In practice, I think you'd rarely want to use that though. The following is *much* more clear... but not nearly as fun.

```
const partialObject = {
  hello: originalObject.hello,
  your: originalObject.your,
};
```

Another completely different route, which includes mucking with the prototype (careful now...):

```
if (!Object.prototype.pluck) {
  Object.prototype.pluck = function(...props) {
    return props.reduce((destObj, prop) => {
      destObj[prop] = this[prop];

      return destObj;
    }, {});
  }
}

const originalObject = {
  hello: 'nurse',
  meaningOfLife: 42,
  your: 'mom',
};

const partialObject2 = originalObject.pluck('hello', 'your');

console.log(partialObject2); // { hello: 'nurse', your: 'mom' }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the most readable and shortest solution I could come up with:

```
let props = { 
  isValidDate: 'yes',
  badProp: 'no!',
};

let { isValidDate } = props;
let newProps = { isValidDate };

console.log(newProps);
```

It will output `{ isValidDate: 'yes' }`

It would be nice to some day be able to say something like `let newProps = ({ isValidDate } = props)` but unfortunately it is not something ES6 supports.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a beautiful way, nor I recommend it, but it's possible this way, just for knowledge.

```js
   const myObject = {
      name: 'foo',
      surname: 'bar',
      year: 2018
    };

    const newObject = ['name', 'surname'].reduce(
      (prev, curr) => (prev[curr] = myObject[curr], prev),
      {},
    );

    console.log(JSON.stringify(newObject)); // {"name":"foo","surname":"bar"}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON class methods to achieve it as follows

```
const foo = {
   x: "bar",
   y: "baz"
};

const oof = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(foo, ['x','y']));
// output -> {x: "bar", y: "baz"}
```

Pass properties that need to be added to the resulting object as second argument to `stringify` function in an array format.

[MDN Doc for JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 0):

With destructuring syntax? Yes, in one line:

```
var foo = {
  x: "bar",
  y: "baz"
}

var oof = {... {x,y} = foo}
```

Gets "x" and "y" from "foo" and spreads these into the new object