# Spread object into object with ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Trying to do the following:

```
let obj = {
    user: 'john',
    foo: 'bar',
    someKey,
    ...KeyParse.explode(model.key) // returns an object
};
```

Is there any way to do the above? ie. spread the object returned from `KeyParse.explode()` into `obj`? So all the `KeyParse.explode()` keys would be populated into `obj`...

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a link or a snippet that outlines the documentation for ``KeyParse.explode()``? I can't seem to find a reference to that anywhere.

Comment: Perhaps `Object.assign` would work for your use case?

Comment: I don't think ES6 is introducing anything specifically for that. I'd look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically

Comment: This is a proposed syntax for ES7: https://github.com/sebmarkbage/ecmascript-rest-spread You can use it with Babel if you want. It is commonly used in JSX.

Comment: @AnotherDev: Oh there is. Also have a look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29620686/1048572)

Comment: Thanks, I stand corrected.