# Create a subset object, consisting of only some of the properties of an existing object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is best explained by example.  The following works in es6 to create an object consisting of some of the keys of an existing object:

```
var o = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3}
var {a, c} = o
var subsetObj = {a, c} // will be: {a:1, c:3}
```

There are two downsides here:

1. It took two statments, and two lines, to create the desired subset object
2. We had to pollute the local variable scope by creating the intermediary `a` and `c` variables, which aren't needed locally, except as a means to creating our subset object.

Is there a way to accomplish the same thing in a single statement, without introducing the unnecessary locals `a` and `c`?

Comment: Why does this need a special syntax? Why not use lodash or something, e.g. `var o = {a:1, b: 2, c: 3}; _.pick(o, ['a', 'c'])`

Comment: It doesn't *need* it, it would just be nice.  I would just create a helper function, rather than bring in all of lodash, if I found myself needing it a lot.  This question was specifically about native syntax support -- the problem itself is obviously trivial to solve.

Comment: Totally, just wanted to mention it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no specific syntax for this. You can keep doing:

```
var subsetObj = {a: o.a, c: o.c};
```

If you have more properties or a variable number of properties, create a helper function.

Related: [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620686/218196)

Comment: I was afraid of this.  It's fine in this example, but becomes verbose when you replace `a` and `c` with long variable names.