# Is there any way to simplify this two-line expression? (destructuring and regrouping)

Tags: javascript

Here's the expression:

```
const { property1, property2 } = someObject;
return { property1, property2 };
```

Basically, I want to extract several properties from one object and then create a new object just with those properties. It feels as if it could be expressed in a simpler way, but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620686/is-it-possible-to-destructure-onto-an-existing-object-javascript-es6)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [One-liner to take some properties from object in ES 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25553910/one-liner-to-take-some-properties-from-object-in-es-6)

Comment: how about merging the objects? then returning the value

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the lodash pick method ([Lodash Pick Documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/#pick)) this will give a one-liner.

```js
const obj = { property1: "property1", property2: "property2", property3: "property3"};

function testPick(someObject) {
    return _.pick(someObject, ["property1", "property2"]);
}

console.log("testPick: ", testPick(obj));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a higher order function to extract an object with specific properties:

```js
const pick = (...p) => o => p.reduce((a, k) => Object.assign(a, { [k]: o[k] }), {})

// usage
const someObject = {
  property1: 'property1',
  property2: 'property2',
  property3: 'property3'
}
// function that extracts these two properties from an object
const pair = pick('property1', 'property2')

console.log(someObject)
console.log(pair(someObject))
```

You could also define `pick()` this way, though the inner function would use stack memory proportional to the amount of keys extracted:

```js
const pick = (...p) => o => Object.assign({}, ...p.map(k => ({ [k]: o[k] })))

// usage
const someObject = {
  property1: 'property1',
  property2: 'property2',
  property3: 'property3'
}
// function that extracts these two properties from an object
const pair = pick('property1', 'property2')

console.log(someObject)
console.log(pair(someObject))
```