# JS - Destructuring by picking only what you need

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to understand ES6, specifically destructuring feature.

How can I translate these lines using destructuring?

```
  const user = {...}
  const sessionData = ({
      session_id: user.session_id, 
      selector: user.selector, 
      validator: user.validator
  })
```

I tried

```
const sessionData = {session_id, selector, validator} = user
```

But it raises a syntax error, because of course destructuring is for giving a certain variable a value from an object but I don't understand how to do something like this with an `object`

Comment: not quite sure what you're trying to do with `user`. To get the data into variables you'd simply use `let {session_id, selector, validator} = sessionData`

Comment: Are you trying to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620686/691711 ?

Comment: You have to do it in two steps, destructure to just the props you need then rebuild the new object with shorthand.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
const { session_id, selector, validator } = user;
```

Then

```
const sessionData = { session_id, selector,  validator };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it like so (using anonymous functions)

```js
const user = { session_id: 1, selector: "my-selector", validator: 1, unused: 3 };
const session = (({ session_id, selector, validator }) => ({ session_id, selector, validator }))(user);
console.log(session);
```

Comment: This is also called an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to create the new object with the fields you want.

```js
const original = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const pick = (o, fields) => fields.reduce((acc, key) => {

    acc[key] = o[key];

    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(pick(original, ['a', 'b']));
```

Or use the [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) to destructure and assign.

```js
const original = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

const newone = ({ a, b } = original, { a, b });

console.log(newone);
```

But keep in mind that the comma operator creates global variables, if the variables to assign the destructure are not declared. Hope this helps.