# How to grab JavaScript destructured parameters independent of variable name?

Tags: javascript

## Wish to enact upon arguments but with defaults defined

In my quest for self-documenting code with destructuring but being DRY wanting to do this...

```
async function shampoo({ lather = true, rinse = true, repeat = 2 } = {}) {
  await api.dogWasherMachine(magicalArguments) // ???
  // don't want to have to do this:
  // api.dogWasherMachine({ lather, rinse, repeat })
  // currenty arguments is {} and actual input is defined
}
```

How do I get these magical arguments that are defined?

**arguments** do not have the default input defined but how can I do this?

Comment: It's really not at all clear what you're talking about here.

Comment: You cannot, you must manually assemble a new object with only those properties.

Comment: Do you want to do `await api.dogWasherMachine(arguments[0])`?

Comment: @Pointy I clarified but seems another user was keen.

Comment: You can destruct the arguments inside the scope...

Comment: you could move the destructuring into the `dogWasherMachine` function ( so your function definitions would look like :`function dogWasherMachine({ lather: true, rinse: true, repeat: 2 })` and `function shampoo(params={})` and then call `dogWasherMachine(params)`

Comment: If I ever become a recruiter, at least I know how to make honey.

Comment: Your destructuring assignment is actually invalid. It should be `async function shampoo({ lather = true, rinse = true, repeat = 2 } = {})`

Comment: @BlueWater86 good call, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to do it in the parameters alone - destructuring *necessarily* extracts each property into an independent named variable, without leaving a reference to the original object behind. You'll have to do it with another statement, eg:

```
async function shampoo(param = {}) {
  const defaultObj = {
    lather: true,
    rinse: true,
    repeat: 2
  };
  await api.dogWasherMachine({ ...defaultObj, ...param });
}
```

Comment: I like this answer as it accomplishes what I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I use destructuring assignment to to self document inheritable classes that are used as interfaces. On construction I get all of the benefits of intellisense and when calling an API everything stays nice and DRY.

```
class washable {
  constructor({ lather = true, rinse = true, repeat = 2 } = {}) {
    this.lather = lather
    this.rinse = rinse
    this.repeat = repeat
  }
}

class dog extends washable {
  async shampoo() {
     await api.dogWasherMachine(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: but... count the number of times you wrote "repeat".

Comment: Agreed but without destructing assignment in your function call (like in your question) how is the function self documenting to external code?

Comment: Yah you are right and thanks for the answer. I would probably use TypeScript in that case.

Comment: I assume by TypeScript you mean JSDoc definitions? Personally I would like to see the ability to destructure directly onto an instance through a class method similar to the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40624564/3236706)