# Prefer destructuring - already exisiting variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, eslint, destructuring

my linter is giving me trouble about destructuring.

[image]

---

When I'm trying to destructure, it makes me an error, like in the following snippet :

```js
const data = {
  status: 'example',
};

let status = 'foo';

{
  status,
} = data;

console.log(status);
```

Is there any ways to use destructuration when the variable already exists?

---

Using `let` again :

```js
const data = {
  status: 'example',
};

let status = 'foo';

let {
  status,
} = data;

console.log(status);
```

Comment: Missing statement `let` `->` `let {
  status
} = data;`  This will raise an error because the variable already exists, so do this `->` `let {
  status: myOwnStatus
} = data;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620686/is-it-possible-to-destructure-onto-an-existing-object-javascript-es6)

Comment: Well it's literally the same. Just add parens.

Comment: I've badly expressed myself. I meant that there was no answer fitting what I wanted to do. @adiga answer is perfect

Comment: But there is a fitting answer in the question I have linked. It's the first answer, which is by the way also the accepted answer. It says "just add the parens around the destructuring". I will quote the second line of the accepted answer: `({x: oof.x, y: oof.y} = foo);`

Comment: @ritaj Right I didn't saw it properly ^^' my bad thx for the input

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add parenthesis around destructuring

From the documentation: [Assignment without declaration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assignment_without_declaration)

> The parentheses ( ... ) around the assignment statement are required when using object literal destructuring assignment without a declaration.
>
> `{a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}` is not valid stand-alone syntax, as the `{a, b}` on the left-hand side is considered a block and not an object literal.
>
> However, `({a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2})` is valid, as is `var {a, b} = {a: 1, b: 2}`
>
> Your ( ... ) expression needs to be preceded by a semicolon or it may be used to execute a function on the previous line.

```js
const data = {
  status: 'example',
};

let status = 'foo';

({ status } = data);

console.log(status);
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much! Is it a trick or does it have a real reason to work that way?

Comment: Could you present a link to the quote?