# how do I retrieve specified properties from a object

Tags: javascript

Let's say we have a `Person` object as:

```
let person = {
   name: "Tom",
   age: "18",
   postcode: 1234,
   city: "Sydney"
}
```

Now I want to retrieve the `name` and `age` properties and assign them to a new object called `student` as:

```
{ name: "Tom", age: "18" }
```

I can definitely manually create the `student` object like so:

```
let student= {
   name: person.name,
   age: person.age
}
```

But the problem is I have to know properties names such as "name" and "age" in advance, so there is no intellisense support in an IDE like Visual Studio Code when I type properties' names
or
I can use rest operator as:

```
let { postcode, city, ...student} = person;
```

But this approach is not very straightforward because I still need to know how many properties in an object and for my case, `student` object is a very simple object, but it will be error-prone if there is a dozen of properties in one object and I just want to retrieve one or two of them.
how can I do that in a most concise and efficient way?

**Edited:**

I actually meant that if there is an easy and advanced feature so I can get the job done in one statement as:

```
let student = { person.name, person.age };  // not valid syntax, I know

or

let student = { get person.name, get person.age };  // non existent syntax, but you get the idea
```

so I can rely on intellisense to define everything.
It seems like I need to write at least two separate statements to achieve the goal, which doesn't sound right to me, I am new to JS, I can see that this feature could be very useful, how come it is not implemented to get it done in one statement?

Comment: Can you explain the actual criteria you're using for which properties you want to copy?

Comment: This question is unclear: *"now I want to retrieve the `name` and `age` properties"*... so **you know** the properties you want, isn't that correct?

Comment: Does [Dynamically access object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property) help?

Comment: You will always need to know which properties you want in the new object in order to both create the object and assign the values

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620686/is-it-possible-to-destructure-onto-an-existing-object-javascript-es6)

Comment: `I have to know properties names such as "name" and "age" in advance` - yes, so? since you want to get `name` and `age`, so you already  "know" the property names you want - I fail to see the issue

Comment: OP: Stack Overflow is a quite active community, so when asking a question please stick around for at least 5 minutes, to see the comments requiring clarification. Voted to close as *unclear*.

Comment: @Barmar  I have updated my post  to address my actual question

Comment: Are you sure you even need two different objects? Why not just `let student = person;`? Since the property names are the same, any function that expects a student will work with a person.

Comment: @Barmar well, it works, but it also means that I have unwanted properties in my object, which can confuses other developers when they received this object, unwanted properties also take up extra memory usage

Comment: @Barmar  so there is no a single statement solution? if there is no such a solution, I appreciate the fact. It just weird to me that such a successful language doesn't offer this useful feature

Comment: Sorry, no. Destructuring can be used to extract properties into variables. There's also object shorthand `{name, age}` that can create properties from variables. But there's no properties->properties shortcut.

Comment: How can one object with 4 properties take up more memory than an object with 4 properties alongside another object with 2 properties? Is the person object going away when you create the student object?

Comment: @Barmar that's why I feel strange, why javascript doesn't implement  properties->properties shortcut. For another question you mentioned, according to what you suggest `let student = person;`, I have to include unwanted properties in the new object, those unwanted properties takes extra cost in memory, even though original object is destructed, becuase the new object should have cost less

Comment: When you do `student = person` it's not a new object, the two variables both refer to the *same* object.

Comment: I guess the need for the properties->properties shortcut was not common enough or they couldn't come up with a good syntax for it.

Comment: In most cases where you might want to do this, the right solution is an object-oriented approach, where you use classes and subclasses.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a class, e.g.

```
class Student {
    constructor(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}

let student = new Student(person.name, person.age);
```

You might also consider making `Person` a class and then making `Student` a subclass of it, then you wouldn't need two different objects.

Answer (score -1):

Create a function which takes object and array of properties to be extracted as arguments. Then create an empty object add the given properties to that object and return it.

```js
const getProps = (obj, props) => 
     props.reduce((ac,a) => {
        ac[a] = obj[a];
        return ac;
     },{});

let person = {
   name: "Tom",
   age: "18",
   postcode: 1234,
   city: "Sydney"
}

console.log(getProps(person, ['name', 'age']))
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this may help. Might not be the full answer, I do not fully understand what your asking to be honest.

You can access an object using a string like so

```
myObject[string]
```

Example ...

```
Let myFields = ["name", "age", "postcode"];

let myObject = {};

myFields.forEach(f => myObject[f] = "");

console.log(myObject);

// { name: "", age: "", postcode: "" }
```

Example 2 ...

```
let myObject = {};

myObject["name"] = "Daniel";
myObject["age"] = 32;
myObject["postcode"] = "78UH4";

console.log(myObject);

// { name: "", age: "", postcode: "" }

myObject.city = "Thurles";

console.log(myObject["city"])

// Thurles
```

How this helps with the struggle

Daniel