# ES6 Destructuring with this inside a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that returns a tuple `[number, number, number]`. I want to use destructuring to assign to my class variables the values returned by the tuple like this:

```
let [this.a, this.b, this.c] = functionThatReturnsTupleWithThreeNumbers()
```

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620686/is-it-possible-to-destructure-onto-an-existing-object-javascript-es6)

Comment: no I need to destructre a tuple not an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the props in your class and destruct your tuple into them:

```
class MyClass {
    a: number;
    b: number;
    c: number;

    constructor(tuple: ReadonlyArray<number>) {
        [this.a, this.b, this.c] = tuple;
    }
}
```

Comment: @kaki6876, it will work with number[] as well. It is just a good practice because a tuple is usually immutable

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the `let` and you're good to go:

```js
class Foo {
    a;
    b;
    c;

    bar() {
        [this.a, this.b, this.c] = [1, 2, 3];
    }
}

const foo = new Foo();
foo.bar();

console.log(foo);
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Typescript [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8CwAoaXpgPwC5oA7AVwFsAjAUwCcBuDbaCg486+x7YV0y2hui5Zg8IhAAuNEsAnwaACgCUKYU2gBtCQAsAlhAB0YADTQd+gxVPnDwALrQAvJoCMpgEymAzHcFMAvhiBQuii4hLQAGaITsRUAO5wiMqCGGEQ8CBUBiDwAOYK0fBKdEA)

Comment: It does - click the run button 