# Destructure object and assign to another object in one line

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Is there a way to do the following in one line?

```js
let person = {}

const { firstName, lastName } = getNames()
//or this
//const { firstName, lastName } = await getNames()

person.firstName = firstName
person.lastName = lastName
```

I often do this when coding, and hoping there is a shortcut. I can not see any hints on how to do this on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment.

I was trying something like the below however, it overrides the other properties in the object.

```js
let person = { age: 20 }
person = { ...getNames() }
```

I don't think this will work well with async/await functions either, as they return a promise.

```js
let person = { age: 20 }
person = { ...await getNames() }
```

Comment: Do you want something like this? [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object? (Javascript ES6)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620686)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably try something like this:

```js
({firstName: person.fistName, lastName: person.lastName} = getNames());
```

You would need `person` defined as an object beforehand.

Comment: Does this approach scale if `person` isn't an empty object? For example if it is defined as `let person = { age: 20 }` before running your suggested code.

Comment: Yes it does. I updated the answer. The object needs to be defined. If it has the keys, they will be replaced. If it doesn't have the keys, they will get added to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Object.assign for this.. For example.

```
let person = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', age: 67, //etc... }

let newPerson = Object.assign(person, getNames()) 

console.log(newPerson)

// Expected output: `{ firstName: 'newFirstName', lastName: 'newLastName', age: 67, etc... }`
```

You can view more on Object.assign here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign