# Destructuring and assigning to an instance property

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following:

```
const {title} = {title: "Menu"};

alert( title ); // Menu
```

Now, if I have the following:

```
interface IEntry {title: string}
class Entry { title = 'Xoom' }

entry:IEntry = new Entry()
```

Why doesn't the following work, and what is the correct form?

```
const {title: this.entry.title} = {title: "Menu"}
```

I was expecting the title property value to be assigned to `this.entry.title`.

Comment: This syntax is invalid from js perspective.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to destructure onto an existing object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29620686/1048572)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a `const` declaration if you don't want to declare a new variable but destructure onto an existing object. The correct syntax would be

```
({title: this.entry.title} = {title: "Menu"});
```

See also [Object destructuring without var, let or const](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27386234/1048572).