# Parse JSON body but whitelist properties in express or typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, express

I have this endpoint in my express server:

```
app.post('/users', express.json(), async (request, response, next) => {
    try {
        console.log(`${request.method} ${request.url} was called.`);
        let user: User = request.body;
        let sessionId: string = request.query.sessionId as string;
        let captcha: string = request.query.captcha as string;
        let errors: string[] = await UserStore.CreateUser(elastic, smtp, user, sessionId, captcha);
        response.status(errors.length <= 0 ? 201 : 400).send(errors);
    }
    catch (error) {
        next(error);
    }
});
```

Additionally, this is my `User` class:

```
export class User {

    public Username: string;
    public Password: string;
    public Email: string;
    public EmailVerified: boolean;
    public Country: string;
    public State: string;
    public City: string;
    public Gender: string;
    public BirthdayTicks: number;

}
```

Is there a standard way in express or typescript to only parse and generate a whitelisted set of properties for a new `User` class from the JSON body, or do I have to `new` one up and set properties on it manually?

The problem right now is that `request.body` may have additional properties that don't exist in the model of a `User` or properties such as `EmailVerified`, which I don't want the user to be able to set themselves. If these go to the elastic server, they will be indexed.

Comment: A related answer that copies only whitelisted properties to a new object using a table-driven approach: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580656/suggest-how-to-write-this-more-compact/72580978#72580978.  There really isn't a cleaner way - you will have to copy over only the properties you want.  I'd suggest you create a constructor for your User object that accepts an object with a bunch of properties and that constructor can then do the safe copy of only the properties it wants.

Comment: I would suggest for cases like this you write JSON Schema to validate your inputs, and have it explictly throw HTTP errors if there's unecognized properties. Ignoring might make it less robust.