# How to set destructured values on properties?

Tags: typescript

I have a simple function that returns 2 values, I hoped I could destructure the return of the function into the `sort` and `sortOrder` in the filters object, but if I do that I get the error:

> Property 'sort' does not exist on type 'DashboardSortingPreferences'.

```js
const { this.filters.sort, this.filters.sortorder } = this.dashboardColumnSortingService.initializeDashboardSortProperties(
    this.user,
    this.dashboardName,
);
```

```js
const { sorted_column, direction } = this.dashboardColumnSortingService.initializeDashboardSortProperties(
    this.user,
    this.dashboardName,
);

this.filters.sort = sorted_column;
this.filters.sortorder = direction;
```

This works, and I understand why, but I was wondering if it was possible to set the `sort_column` and `direction` directly on the `sort` and `sortOrder` properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Related answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29620686/is-it-possible-to-destructure-onto-an-existing-object-javascript-es6)

It is possible. On the [mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) we can read:

```
const numbers = [];
const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };
({ a: numbers[0], b: numbers[1] } = obj);
// The properties `a` and `b` are assigned to properties of `numbers`
```

so in your case it would look something like this:

```
({ sorted_column: this.filters.sort, direction: this.filters.sortorder } = 
this.dashboardColumnSortingService.initializeDashboardSortProperties(
this.user,
this.dashboardName));
```

Comment: Waw. I hate it, but waw